# Pandas Encoding German

Tags: pandas, encoding, utf-8

This might sound like a simple question but I´ve tried everything I´ve found online.
I want to load a CSV into my pandas dataframe with all characters being displayed correctly.
When uploading it the following way:

```
df = pd.read_csv('round2.csv', sep=';', encoding = "utf-8", engine='python')
```

I get an error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 3319: invalid continuation byte
```

When using "Latin-1" or "ISO-8859-1", there is no error in the reading but the data is displayed the following way

[image]
[image]

So I have the same characters displayed in two different ways in the same CSV file.

When opening the CSV in Notepad++, the columns ('Unternehmen L1, etc.) are displayed correctly but the columns ('Anfang L1, etc.) aren´t. Instead of "ä", I get "xE4" there.

Thx for helping me.

Comment: When reading the file as an xlsx, the datecolumns turn into datetime which results in no error when loading the dataset. However, the characters are still displayed incorrectly although using utf-8, latin-1 and ISO-8859-1.